# jquery using .load method for drop down list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

**How do i use jquery ajax .load function for dropdownlist?**

this is my php page

```
<? 
$query="SELECT Name FROM supplier";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="ddlSupplier">
<option>Supplier Name</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value><?=$row['Name']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

how do i get value after load?

```
$("#ddlSupplier").val()? this.val()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your markup on which you call `.load()`, so I'm gonna use `#placeholder` as the selector to which you will be injecting the dropdown:

```
$('#placeholder').load('yourphppage.php', function(html) {
   $(this).find('select[name=ddlSupplier]').val();
});
```

Note that the callback is called after HTML insertion, so you can do `find()`. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it as you said with `.val()`

```
$(function () {
     $("#ddlSupplier").on('change', function () {
         var value = $(this).val();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

First in the PHP, you are trying to select the dropdown via an `ID` but you aren't setting one. So that's added. Also, you aren't actually providing a value to the `<option>`'s, so that's added too.

```
<? 
$query="SELECT Name FROM supplier";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select id="ddlSupplier" name="ddlSupplier">
<option>Supplier Name</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row['Name']?>"><?=$row['Name']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Finally, in the JS, you need to get the value of the selection option, rather than the value of the `select` list (as the `select` doesn't have a value).

```
$("#ddlSupplier option:selected").val()
```